# Consume my own api with laravel can't take get parameters

Tags: php, api, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I'm working with laravel 4 and we have our own rest API and I can't take the data with laravel using GET.

If I put the url in the browser I can see all the info. Example:

```
   http://myroutedotcom/v1/categories?entity_id=1&category_id=1
```

[image: In the browser]

Now in laravel, on the view, I have this code and returns 404:

```
    $parameters = array (
      'category_id' => 1,
      'entity_id' =>1
    );

    $request = Request::create('/v1/categories', 'GET', $parameters);

    $response = json_decode(Route::dispatch($request)->getContent());

    var_dump($response);
```

[image: Api fail]

Any contribution will be welcome!

Comment: For now I have solved using this:
$json = file_get_contents('http://mydomaindotcom/v1/categories?entity_id=1&category_id=1');
$obj = json_decode($json);

Answer (score 2):

```
    $parameters = array (
        'entity_id' =>$city_id,
        'category_id' =>$category_id
    );

$request = Request::create('/v1/places', 'GET', $parameters);
Request::replace($request->input());
$data_places = json_decode(Route::dispatch($request)->getContent());
```

The key is in this line:
Request::replace($request->input());